# Problems with QTMovie and .m3u8

Tags: macos, cocoa, streaming, qtkit

I'm trying to make an app for OS X for playing .m3u8 urls videos.

I tried to use this code:

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url.m3u8"];
QTMovie* movie = [[QTMovie alloc] initWithURL: movieURL error: nil]; 
[_movieView setMovie:movie]; 
[_movieView play: self];
```

But the video doesn't start, and I get a "-2048" error.

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried

```
[_movieView setMovie:[QTMovie movieWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.m3u8"] error:nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in `MacErrors.h`. The `-2048` error resolves to `noMovieFound`. This means that your movie URL is incorrect.

When you use the `setMovie:error:` message, pass in an `NSError` object so you can see what the error is! That's the whole point of the `NSError` parameter.